# Transform scaleX relative to other elements

Tags: css

I want whenever I scale - adjacent elements to move accordingly. How can I do that? Whenever I do scale it goes on top of adjacent element.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/caviki/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

In opposite to that if I change `width` value it works as I wanted, yet I can't use `width` in transitions.

HTML:

```
  <input>
  <div class="foo">
```

CSS:

```
input{
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s ease;  
  transform-origin:left;
}
input:focus{
  transform: scaleX(2)
}

.foo{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You absolutely can use `width` in transitions.

Comment: oh that's right! It never occurred to me that you have to set both - initial and transitioned state width *explicitly*. Thank you. Yet for the sake of curiosity - why transforms ignore adjacent elements?

Comment: You have to think of `scale` like `zoom`, it doesn't affect the DOM flow at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to set both an initial and a destination value for your transitions, like so:

```
input{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: width 1s ease;  
  transform-origin:left;
  width: 100px;
}
input:focus{
  width: 200px
}
```

## [JSBin illustrating this here](http://jsbin.com/caviki/2/)